# mysql view with user variables

Tags: mysql, view

I have a query that calculate distance from point a to point b using gps coordinates, and would like to make it view.

Is it posible to pass variables that will replace xxx and yyy in my query with variables passed from outside of view?

Here's query.

```
select 
    round((((degrees(acos(((sin(radians(xxx)) * sin(radians(`ag_regija_hr`.`lat`))) + 
         ((cos(radians(xxx)) * cos(radians(`ag_regija_hr`.`lat`))) *
           cos(radians((yyy - `ag_regija_hr`.`lng`))))))) * 60) * 1.1515) * 1.609344), 2) AS `dist`
from
    `ag_regija_hr` 
order by `dist`
```

Answer (score -1):

check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql

ot you can crate sp for this select
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html